# Is there a term or idiom for a relationship that took a very long time to consummate?

Tags: expressions

I am looking for a term or expression to describe people who clearly have very strong feelings for each other but, for reasons beyond their control, were unable to be together for a long time.

I feel unrequited love isn't the right term as neither side rejects the other.

Comment: The Victorians referred to a 'long engagement', when a man had to wait to marry until he could financially support a wife and the inevitable family (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Engagement) - but that doesn't apply to modern circumstances.

Comment: @KateBunting- I like that one, thank you, it's certainly the closest I've seen yet.

Comment: Are you looking for 'long-awaited' togetherness?

Comment: Maybe a "slow blooming" relationship?

Comment: Perhaps the term you're looking for is a ***platonic** relationship.* Or maybe [this from Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-crossed) ***star-crossed lovers** is a phrase describing a pair of lovers whose relationship is often thwarted by outside forces.*

Comment: . . . .  'lifelong courtship' [NY Times 1995](https://www.nytimes.com/1995/12/05/world/the-neediest-cases-after-a-lifelong-courtship-spurning-the-needle.html).

Comment: The title asks to describe a relationship, the body asks to describe people.  An example sentence would help make clear which one is right.

Comment: is 'be together" a synonym for "to consummate"?

Comment: @green_ideas This crack me up. LOL!

Comment: FF's (though I think someone even more famous famously used the term) 'starcrossed lovers' seems appropriate. Though it connotes real drama, merely being unable to spend much quality time together licenses the phrase.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - star crossed lovers is closer. I am thinking of a mutual love that could not be, for external reasons like politics, or religion or social taboo, but after a long struggle was eventually able to flourish. The phrase "hard won" might be apropos if it didn't sound so unromantic.

Comment: Unfulfilled? . . .

Comment: The question, as it now stands, is ambiguous between (a) not being in a romantic relationship, and (b) being in a romantic relationship that is not consummated. The OP's last comment indicates that (a) was intended, but, if so, the question needs to be edited to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

I  see  ***long-delayed** romance,* if you find nothing better.

> Wild Wine (1932) relates the **decade-long delayed romance** between a
> couple who are ... [Clarence Andrews; *Chicago in Story: A Literary
> History*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Chicago_in_Story/nqtZAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22long-delayed%20romance%22&dq=%22long-delayed%20romance%22&printsec=frontcover) (1982)

> Not giving Elizabeth any hint whom I was expecting, I continued to
> bask in the simple joy of her nearness, the rekindling of our **long
> delayed romance**. [Peter Mt. Shasta; *Adventures of a Western Mystic*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Adventures_of_a_Western_Mystic/IBkKZPZLy0kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22long-delayed%20romance%22&pg=PA111&printsec=frontcover)
> (2010)

> It was sometime than five months later when I renewed my **long
> delayed romance** with my girlfriend, Nora Murphy, and we're now
> planning to have a November wedding. [Richard Johnson; *Sunken Spanish
> Treasure Quest*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/SUNKEN_SPANISH_TREASURE_QUEST/TZ52BAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22long-delayed%20romance%22&pg=PA425&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

Answer (score 0):

> **situationship**
>
> A relationship that has no label on it.. like a friendship but more than a friendship but not quite a relationship.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Situationship)

I picked up this *"word"* from a 14 year old recently. I find it rather descriptive of the situation you have described.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really cool word, but what I'm looking for is something that conveys a passion that cannot be - people who are really in love but cannot express that, and cannot be together for some external reason.

Comment: ***complicated*** lol